# Does swagger (OpenAPI) support declaring types that are sub types of String or other primatives

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

In my API a `UUID` is not returned as its internal model instead it is returned as a string. This means if we have a `UUID` in the API it looks like

```
"uuid"
```

rather than:

```
{id: "uuid"}
```

Currently I tell `springfox` that `UUID` is a `String`, however this results in behavior where `swagger` seems to forget which `strings` are really `UUIDs`. Types which include a `UUID` in them, are changed so that instead they say they contain a `string` so the consumer of the `swagger` doc is no longer aware which parts of the `json` model is a `UUID`.

Does `swagger` support declaring types that are just a subset of a primitive, in this case I want to declare that the type `UUID` exists but tell swagger that a `UUID` just looks the same as a string?

Bonus question: if this is possible under `swagger` how can I declare this under `springfox`.